# Distinct count of items in a column except the one selected from slicer DAX

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, olap-cube

I am trying to write a dax for the following query:

```
select EncounterID
,EncounterDateKey 
,DxCode
,DxID  
into #PatEnc
from table1
where EncounterDateKey = 20180601
  and DxCode = 'Z00.00'

select count(distinct(dbf.DiagnosisCode))
from #PatEnc    
 left outer join tabel1 dbf on dbf.EncounterID = 
  #PatEnc.EncounterID
 where dbf.DxCode != 'Z00.00'
```

My fact table has following structure

```
EncounterID      EncounterDateKey     DxCode     DxID
1                20180601             Z00.00      1
1                20180601             Z00.01      2
1                20180601             D00.00      3
2                20180601             A00.0       4
2                20180601             Z00.00      1
3                20180601             B00.00      5
3                20180601             F0.0        6
```

so the Dax code should return the count as 3 as there are 3 different Dx Code for the Encounters that were selected when Z00.00 was selected from the slicer. I tried filter and except function for the DAX code but its not brigning the accurate results.

I get the value selected in the slicer but couldn't get the count of remaining values. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer edited, after question updated:

This query returns a distinct count of non-selected `DxCode(s)` for `Encounter ID(s)` associated with the selected `DxCode(s)`:

```
Count Unselected = 
VAR SelectedDxCodes = VALUES ( Table1[DxCode] )
VAR SelectedEncounterIDs = VALUES ( Table1[EncounterID] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[DxCode] ),
        ALL ( Table1[DxCode] ),
        ALL ( Table1[EncounterID] ),
        NOT ( Table1[DxCode] IN SelectedDxCodes ),
        Table1[EncounterID] IN SelectedEncounterIDs
    )
```

It currently returns `BLANK` if no `DxCode` slicer selection is made, as this case isn't explained in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is awesome. It works only if 1 value is selected in the slicer. there is a chance that user might select multiple values from the slicer. Also, the distinct count is not working as expected. In the above example where I select Z00.00 there are 2 encounters that will get selected and when I do distinct count on DxCode column, after excluding Z00.00 there are 3 codes that will be left. So total 5 rows and 3 distinct code after excluding the one selected from slicer. Apologies for the wrong number above.

Comment: Thanks, @Olly for the reply.